# Why does it say "unfortunately -- has stopped"?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm working on something like a note app. I am pretty new to this and I wonder why it says "unfortunately -- has stopped". The start activity is called start and when a button is pressed you should get to this "pg2" activity but the app just stopps. I think it is something abot the getSharedPreferences. Please help, here is the link: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/97063669/error.png

[image: error text]

Comment: Please post your log trace.

Comment: Examine LogCat to see the Java stack trace associated with your error. Also, please post your source code as source code, not as an image.

Comment: Did you save something with the ID String first?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the error occurs when you click of refText, then the error is likely caused by when you attempt to get your string String out of shared preferences. You should supply an actual string, even an empty one, as the default rather than a null.

So the line could be something like:

```
final String String=sgarePrefences.getString("String", "");
```

Comment: By the way, using the name of a Class/type for a instance/variable name will eventually cause you lots of debugging grief. I recommend you at least use something like myString.

Answer (score 0):

The logcat doesn't make sense to me -.- The error occurs when i press the button on the start activity and not the ref button. If i try to delete the sharedprefernce thing there is no error. I can't post the code here, it doesn't work (probably me who is retarded)

Comment: Please edit to your question to add more information. Please do not post it as an answer.